# Why does my Python thread block the main thread unless I add a print or a sleep?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-internals

Does anyone know why running this code causes the script to hang in the thread, unless I uncomment the print, the sleep, or the "if" condition, or remove the try/except? My understanding is that this thread shouldn't block the main thread.

```
import threading
import time  # noqa

class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.thread_loop, daemon=True)
        self.keep_looping = True
        self.a = 0

    def start_thread(self) -> None:
        self.thread.start()

    def stop_thread(self) -> None:
        self.keep_looping = False
        print('stop')

    def thread_loop(self) -> None:
        print('thread_loop')
        while self.keep_looping:
            try:
                # print('loop')
                # time.sleep(0.1)
                self.a += 1
                # if self.a == 'xxxx':
                #     print(self.a)
                #     time.sleep(0.1)
            except Exception as err:
                print(err)


blinky = Something()
print('start')
blinky.start_thread()
print('stop')
blinky.stop_thread()
print('done')
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? This works on my computer.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know why running this code causes the script to hang in the thread...?

I don't see your script hanging. If I run it, unmodified, I see:

```
start
thread_loop
stop
stop
done
```

It's a little unclear what you're hoping to accomplish here; there's effectively zero time between your call to `start_thread()` and your call to `stop_thread()`, but since `thread_loop()` implements a strictly CPU-bound loop we can show that *something* is happening by adding an additional `print` to the end of your code:

```
blinky = Something()
print('start')
blinky.start_thread()
print('stop')
blinky.stop_thread()
print('done')
print(blinky.a)
```

Given the above code, we see:

```
start
thread_loop
stop
stop
done
159022
```

Showing us that `thread_loop` looped 159,022 times (the actual number will vary based on the speed of your CPU, the number of CPUs in your system, the number of other programs running, etc).

It's *possible* that on your system the loop in `thread_loop` is consuming so much of your CPU that nothing else has the time to run...in which case anything that explicitly sleeps (such as `time.sleep()`) or engages in i/o (such as a `print` statement) would yield control of the processor long enough for another thread to run.

Threading in Python is primarily useful when your code is **not** primarily CPU bound. Because of the [global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), multiple threads in Python are *not* able to run in parallel, leading to the situation I described in the previous paragraph.